# Solve for x for the following description

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Let $x$ be a perfect square and a natural number. When $x$ is divided by $5$, the quotient is $[x]$ and the remainder is $\{x\}$. Then solve for x if 
$$\sqrt{x}+\{x\}=[x]$$

My attempt is as follows:

$$x=5[x]+\{x\}$$
$$[x]=5[x]$$
$$[x]=0$$

This means $x\in [0,1)$ but x is a natural number, so the given condition is contradictory.

I don't know what mistake am I doing. Please help me.

Comment: What is $[x]$ and $\{x\}$

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you defining $[x]$ as the greatest integer $≤x$ and $\{x\}=x-[x]$?

Comment: yes, I assumed that because no other definition is given

Comment: Well, that's not true.  You also define $[x], {x}$ to be the quotient, remainder of $x$ divided by $5$.

Comment: Perhaps the intended question is, writing a natural number $x$ as $x=5y+z$ with $z\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and assuming that $\sqrt x +z=y$, solve for $x$.  If so, it isn't a good idea to use notation which is standardly applied to a different definition.

Comment: @user3290550 What is the context of the problem ? How did you come across this?

Comment: greatest integer , so that's why I assumed the same definition

Comment: @lulu , if only two equations are given in three variables, how to solve it

Comment: I have no idea if my version of the question is what you intended. If my some chance I have it right, then I am not sure there is a unique solution.

Comment: Just ran some quick tests.  With my version of the question, I see that $x=25,36,64$ all work, for example.  To see that $64$ works, for instance, note that $64=5\times 12+4$ so $y=12,z=4$.  And then note that $\sqrt {64}+4=12$ as desired.  $y$ grows much faster than $\sqrt x+z$ so it should be easy to show that $64$ is the largest example.

Answer (score 0):

$$x=5[x]+\{x\}$$ 
$$ x=5(\sqrt x +\{x\})+\{x\}$$

$$x=5\sqrt x +6\{x\}$$

Note that $36=5\sqrt {36}+6(1)$

Therefore $x=36$ is a solution.

Also $64$ is a solution

Comment: but through trial and error case, you miss some solutions, like here you missed 25

Comment: @user3290550   Thanks for your attention.Yes, I missed  25 as well.